# second cycle of validation function wont validate correctly

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct time{int hours, mins, secs;};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


printf("\nplease enter the time in 24 hr format, \nenter the hours, return,\nenter minutes, return, enter seconds, and return.\n");
struct time one;
scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &one.hours, &one.mins, &one.secs); 
printf("retfal1"); 
int yn; 

yn = validateTime(one, yn); 
while(!yn){ 

            printf("\nerror, please enter the time in 24 hr format, \nenter the hours, return,\nenter minutes, return, enter seconds, and return.\n");
         scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &one.hours, &one.mins, &one.secs);  
         validateTime(one);

      if (!yn){
            puts("Invalid input\nPlease try again"); 
         printf("\nplease enter the time in 24 hr format, \nenter the hours, return,\nenter minutes, return, enter seconds, and return.\n");
         scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &one.hours, &one.mins, &one.secs);  
         validateTime(one);
      }
      else{ 
         printf ("Time entered was; %d:%d:%d", one.hours, one.mins, one.secs);


      }
      }

      printf ("the time entered ws; %d:%d:%d", one.hours, one.mins, one.secs);

  getch();
  return 0;  
} 


int validateTime(struct time tme, int yn)
{

if (tme.hours < 0 || tme.hours > 23 || tme.mins > 59 || tme.mins < 0 || tme.secs < 0 || tme.secs > 59)
{
              printf("retfal4");
     yn = 0;
     return yn;
     }
else {
     printf("rettru");
     yn = 1;
     return yn; 

     }
}
```

this program is supposed to take in, validate and print hours, minutes and seconds (taking them in on separate lines) if it gets an invalid input on the first try it will prompt again intake and check the time. the validation is causing issues, it will validate correctly on the first entry, however if you put in an incorrect time it will give an invalid output and prompt for the next input however even a correct/valid input will bring up another invalid entry prompt... I have been looking at this for far too long, I can tell I've done something stupid at some stage but can't find it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `yn` only once, before the loop. Inside the loop you call `validateTime()` again, but you don't evaluate its result. As a result, once `yn` is set to false, it is never reset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are passing the variable `yn` into your validate function. Just return 0 or 1 should be fine. May not solve your problem.

Your problem is that you are not setting `yn` to the result of calling your validate function inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the result of `validateTime` in `yn` like you do the first time you call it.

I also think you may be wanting to take in a `int *yn` in `validateTime` so you can update the variable passed to it, otherwise it wouldn't make sense to take an extra `int` as an argument. I would simply remove that argument and store the return value.

As this is homework, I don't want to change your code for you but suggest alternatives.